# Строки string и const char []

Tags: c++, строки

Есть конструктор, принимающий параметром `const char []`. Как сделать так, чтобы он принимал и строки типа `string`?

Comment: Сделайте 2 конструктора.

Answer (score 8):

Если нужно принимать и `const char*`, и `std::string`, то правильнее сделать единый конструктор, принимающий `const std::string&`.

В таком случае сишные строки будут как раз неявно преобразованы в `std::string`. А вот неявного преобразования из `std::string` в `char*` нет, требуется вызывать функцию-член `c_str()`.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно такому конструктору скормить `string`, то так:

```
string str;
FakeClass fake(str.c_str());
```

Comment: Не, я имел в виду, не преобразовывая. Неявное преобразование может быть?

Comment: Или это в принципе невозможно?